# react-native-image-picker doen`t upload to server

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
export const updateUserAvatarResponse = async data => {

const resp = await fetch(config.domain + '/api/users/update/avatar/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + data.access,
    },
    body: new FormData('avatar', {
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        uri: data.avatar.uri,
        name: 'filename.jpg',
        // data: data.avatar,
    }),
});

return await resp.json();
```

};

updateAva = async () => {
const options = {
title: 'Select Avatar',
// noData: false,
storageOptions: {
// skipBackup: true,
path: 'images',
},
// multiple: true,
// includeExif: true,

```
    };

    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
        if (response.uri) {
            this.setState({
                imageData: response.uri,
                data: response
            });
            this.uploadImage();
        }
    });
};

uploadImage = async () => {
    const access = await getAccessToken();

    const resp = await updateUserAvatarResponse({
        access: access,
        avatar: this.state.data
    });

    console.log(this.state.data);

    console.log(resp);
};
```

But get this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJZxo.png)

Comment: comment this line,
initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager())

in file, 
/android/app/src/main/java/com/{your_project}/MainApplication.java

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28551

Comment: Already done it, don`t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem here:

```
body: new FormData('avatar', {
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    uri: data.avatar.uri,
    name: 'filename.jpg',
    // data: data.avatar,
}),
```

You are trying to create new instance of `FormData` by passing there non-valid arguments. According to the [documentation of FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData), this approach of creating FormData is valid when you pass a `HtmlElement` that you can get from `document.getElementById` (as example).

The right way of creating `FormData` in your case would be:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append('avatar', {
   type: 'image/jpeg',
   uri: data.avatar.uri,
   name: 'filename.jpg',
});
```